# How change Row values to Column names (R)

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with COVID19 data. There is one inconvenience. I have a column named location and all countries are under that column. To illustrate, first value is Country A, Date A, next Country A, Date B... Country Z, Date Z. I wonder how can I group all the values by dates and have each country as a separate column?

This is the link of the data:

https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus-source-data

Comment: Please post the data into the question by using `dput(head(yourdata))`.

Comment: I have attached the link to the data

Comment: Please include **reproducible** data in the question.

Comment: A link is no good because it could disappear one day. Aim to make the question completely standalone so that the question and any answers can be read in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape the data using code like the following:

```
df_example = with(df, data.frame(location = location,
                                date = date, 
                                new_cases = new_cases))

df_example = reshape(df_example, timevar = "location", idvar = "date", direction = "wide")
df_example = df_example[order(df_example$date), ]
```

Note here that I kept only one variable as the cell value in the new data frame (i.e., new_cases), because the new data frame is already *very* wide (it has 213 columns now). If you keep additional variables the new data frame will be wider.

```
head(df_example)   # I will not put the output here, you can try yourself
```

The following three lines will make the new data frame look nicer.

```
cnames = names(df_example)[2:ncol(df_example)]
cnames = unlist(lapply(cnames, function(x) substr(x, 11, nchar(x))))
names(df_example)[2:ncol(df_example)] = cnames
```